# Are there any streamliner producers?

Tags: upgrades

Anyone seen ready-made bike aero extensions or streamliner producer ?

Not asking about velomobiles. Looking for something between.

Are there any significant improvements of common bicycle in terms of effectivity (aerodynamics), comfort (covering, waterproof), etc. ?

Links about fairings:
[Could fairings provide the biggest aero gain we’re all missing out on?](https://www.bikeradar.com/features/could-fairings-provide-the-biggest-aero-gain-were-all-missing-out-on/)
[Aerodynamics of Real-World Bicycles](https://janheine.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/aerodynamics-of-real-world-bicycles/)
[SpeedUp bag](https://newatlas.com/aerodynamic-speed-up-handlebar-bag/30716/)

Thinking about kind of small air balloon in front giving a drop shape - probably one of few options to reduce F(C).

Comment: I strongly recommend you research other sources of data outside of youtube quotes and sales guff..  To pick a point - if a disk wheel was 2 watts compared to 15 watts of an aero wheel then they would be used a lot more despite the consequences of windage (being a sail in a side wind)

Comment: Clarification request - what is your actual question?  SE isn't very well suited to open-ended questions or polls or general discussion.

Comment: I'll ask again - what is your question?

Comment: AndyP - experiment finished - after 30(?)km it went a bit out of original position, but best test was company garage - after passive downhill I drived around whole garage and still needed breaks @exit, but with the box I did not need use 'em ;-) Looks like a pro's like aero improvements are better - limit separate obstackles or change their shape to be more eliptic or drop to prevent bad circulations and do not increase front area. Maybe cover space inside frame triangle, etc.

Comment: Please read the [tour] to refresh your memory on how Stackexchange is organised.

Comment: Also, the original post asked about "ready-made bike aero extensions", which sound like clip on aero bars. Tom, this post could be **greatly** improved if you clarified what you are asking about. Are you asking for bike fairings that are short of a full velomobile? The International Cycling Union (UCI) bans fairings in competition for road bikes, so people may not have developed fairings.

Comment: Exactly - velomobile is too big, heavy, overpriced and would guess sensitive to side wind - so probably easier to drive my diesel ;-) Looking for something far from both - for example thought about laying on my StreetStrider, to reduce front area, but complicated to realize and not sure if it would be useful as handbike, also pedals in the middle will be obstacle... But maybe there are alternatives. Example move forward on common, but again where to move sear then, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product recommendations are off-topic for bicycles.se, but yes, there are a few. They mostly cater to recumbent riders. A web search for **bicycle fairing** should give you some options.

There are also **velomobiles**, which are fully or mostly enclosed recumbent trikes sold as a finished product. These are not designed purely for speed--they're usually intended as practical everyday vehicles.